# Rails - deployment problem with HTTP Active Record Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to install a Rails app (Spree E-commerce) on a Digital Ocean droplet using the [Tomo CLI](https://github.com/mattbrictson/tomo) tool. You run it on your local machine, give it the login credentials for the server, and it will deploy your Rails app for you. At least in theory.

I've had problem after problem with Tomo, most of which I've managed to fix. However, I'm at a loss for the current problem, which Tomo encounters when it tries to create the database with `bundle exec rake db:create`. I tried creating the database first, as Tomo seems to skip steps if they are already completed on the server, but that didn't fix anything.

Here is the error message provided by Tomo. Googling has brought me zilch so far. Any help would be great!

```
• rails:db_create
cd /tmp/tomo/20200718051237 && bundle exec rake db:version
cd /tmp/tomo/20200718051237 && bundle exec rake db:create
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from block (2 levels) in require at /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74)
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not load the 'http' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile.
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/tmp/tomo/20200718051237/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/http_adapter
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/tmp/tomo/20200718051237/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

  ERROR: The following script failed on deployer@134.209.110.34 (exit status 1).

    cd /tmp/tomo/20200718051237 && bundle exec rake db:create

  You can manually re-execute the script via SSH as follows:

    ssh -o LogLevel\=ERROR -A -o ConnectTimeout\=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking\=accept-new -o ControlMaster\=auto -o ControlPath\=/var/folders/b1/mqpmy8jj4h74xl88g_wdxr3h0000gn/T/tomo_ssh_91c26631d427a22d -o ControlPersist\=30s -o PasswordAuthentication\=no deployer@134.209.110.34 -- cd\ /tmp/tomo/20200718051237\ \&\&\ bundle\ exec\ rake\ db:create

  For more troubleshooting info, run tomo again using the --debug option.

  DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from block (2 levels) in require at /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74)
  rake aborted!
  LoadError: Could not load the 'http' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile.
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
  /tmp/tomo/20200718051237/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

  Caused by:
  LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/http_adapter
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:198:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
  /tmp/tomo/20200718051237/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  /var/www/ncode-bkk-spree/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

​

Here is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_db
  username: my-user
  password: Rails.application.credentials.db[:dpassword]

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_db

production:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: production_db
  encoding: utf8
  username: my-user
  password: Rails.application.credentials.db[:ppassword]
```